# Parse timestamp to get hours

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp

Is it possible (without multiple queries and temp tables) to pull the hour of day from a timestamp? I've been trying stuff along the lines of:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) FROM ...
```

where 'timestamp' is the name of the TIMESTAMP column. It actually does the trick but I want the hours to be displayed in nice fancy format... basically in 12 hours format like '10:00am' or '9:00pm'...and currently it is just throwing up hours

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,"%h:%i %p") FROM myTable
```

> %h = Hour (01..12)
>
> %i = Minutes, numeric (00..59)
>
> %p = AM or PM

Reference: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Somehow, 'FROM_UNIXTIME' is giving me NULL and i can't really get to bottom of this.

Comment: Then maybe you have a TIMESTAMP format column and not a Unix Timestamp stored as integer: in that case this answer stands void

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%h:%I%p') time
  FROM Table1
```

Sample output:

```
|    TIME |
|---------|
| 01:01AM |
| 03:03AM |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bd55/3)** demo